# Create nested list from two lists

Tags: python

I have got two lists like this:

```
t = [1,2,3,4]
f = ['apples', 'oranges','grapes','pears']
```

I need to create a list of lists like this:

```
data =  [
        ['Fruit', 'Total'],
        ['apples', 1],
        ['oranges', 2],
        ['grapes', 3],
        ['pears' 4]
    ]
```

I have done this:

```
l = []
l.append(['Fruit', 'Total'])
# I guess I should have check that lists are the same size?
for i, fruit in enumerate(f):
    l.append([fruit, t[i]])
```

Just wondering if there is a more Pythonic way of doing this.

Comment: `print zip(f, t)` might interest you, though it returns a list of tuples - not list of lists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and list comprehension is another way to do it. i.e., by doing `l.extend([list(a) for a in zip(f, t)])`:

Demo:

```
>>> t = [1,2,3,4]
>>> f = ['apples', 'oranges','grapes','pears']
>>> l = []
>>> l.append(['Fruit', 'Total'])
>>> l.extend([list(a) for a in zip(f, t)])
>>> l
[['Fruit', 'Total'], ['apples', 1], ['oranges', 2], ['grapes', 3], ['pears', 4]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I like it, but:

```
r = [[f[i], t[i]] if i >= 0 else ['fruit', 'total'] for i in range(-1, len(t))]
```